# Android NDK Include Eigen

Tags: android, c++, matrix, android-ndk

I am trying to include the [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) library in an Android project so I can do some Matrix math in native code.

When I compile my project it complains:

```
In file included from jni/Eigen/Dense:1:0,
                 from jni/Ares.cpp:9:
jni/Eigen/Core:156:22: fatal error: functional: No such file or directory
 #include <functional>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

I thought maybe including the STL would help, so I have an `Application.mk` file which is as follows:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

No dice, though.

Adding `/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/` to my `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable resolves that error, but raises:

```
In file included from jni/Eigen/Core:152:0,
                 from jni/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from jni/Ares.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.9.2/cstdlib:41:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/c++config.h>
```

Is there a way to include Eigen and resolve these issues other than progressively adding most of my machine's headers?

Comment: what  version is your gcc compiler?

Comment: @nkcode: I have `gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) 4.9.2` and `NDK r10e-rc4 (64-bit)`.

Comment: _"Adding /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/ to my LOCAL_C_INCLUDES"_ You should be adding the include directory from your NDK installation; not your host compiler's include directory.

Comment: @Michael, including the host compiler's include directory did make me nervous. I notice there are many include subdirectories within my ndk directory. Which is the right one? How can I include it while being somewhat independent as to target platform?

Comment: I'd say pick the greatest one less than or equal to your minSdkVersion.

Comment: @Michael: Using `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/user/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include` still raises an error `/home/user/Android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cstdlib:41:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Using `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/user/Android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-x86/usr/include`, the compiler cannot find `<functional>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following resolved the aforementioned issue!

1. Create a file called `Application.mk` in the directory `projet_dir/jni/` (so it is `projet_dir/jni/Application.mk`).
2. Add the following line to that file

   ```
   APP_STL:=stlport_static
   ```
3. If you run into a shared_ptr error, try using `APP_STL := gnustl_static` instead.