# Matrix mathematics library for Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, matrix, android-ndk

I am looking for a matrix mathematics library to use with Android NDK.

I have tried using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), figuring that a header-only library would work well, but it has raised [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704311/android-ndk-include-eigen) for me.

[Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) seems to rely on LAPACK, BLAS, ARPACK and SuperLU, which seems as though it could make compilation intractably complex.

Is there a way to include Eigen or an alternative matrix library which is known to work well with NDK?